# Add delimiters at specific indexes

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I want to add a delimiter in some indexes for each line of a file.

I have a file with data:

```
10100100010000
20200200020000
```

And I know the offset of each column (2, 5 and 9)

With this sed command: `sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)/&,/;s/\(.\{6\}\)/&,/;s/\(.\{11\}\)/&,/' myFile`

I get the expected output:

```
10,100,1000,10000 
20,200,2000,20000
```

but with a large number of columns (~200) and rows (300k) is really slow.

Is there an efficient alternative?

Comment: Finally I've tried two solutions (both worked) with 231 columns and 308k, RavinderSingh13's 1st solution takes ~9 sec and Aaron's extended regular expression solution takes ~23 sec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With GNU `awk` could you please try following:

```
awk -v OFS="," '{$1=$1}1' FIELDWIDTHS="2 3 4 5"  Input_file
```

***2nd Solution:*** Using `sed` try following.

```
sed 's/\(..\)\(...\)\(....\)\(.....\)/\1,\2,\3,\4/' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** `awk` solution using `substr`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {print substr($0,1,2) OFS substr($0,3,3) OFS substr($0,6,4) OFS substr($0,10,5)}' Input_file
```

In above `substr` solution, I have taken 5 digits/characters in `substr($0,10,5)` in case you want to take all characters/digits etc starting from 10th position use `substr($0,10)` which will take rest of all line's characters/digits here to print.

Output will be as follows.

```
10,100,1000,10000
20,200,2000,20000
```

Answer (score 5):

Modifying your sed command to make it add all the separators in one shot would likely make it perform better :

```
sed 's/^\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{4\}\)/\1,\2,\3,/' myFile
```

Or with extended regular expression:

```
sed -E 's/(.{2})(.{3})(.{4})/\1,\2,\3,/' myFile
```

Output:

```
10,100,1000,10000
20,200,2000,20000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start the substitutions from the back, you can use the number flag to `s` to specify which occurrence of any character you'd like to append a comma to:

```
$ sed 's/./&,/9;s/./&,/5;s/./&,/2' myFile
10,100,1000,10000
20,200,2000,20000
```

You could automate that a bit further by building the command with a `printf` statement:

```
printf -v cmd 's/./&,/%d;' 9 5 2
sed "$cmd" myFile
```

or even wrap that in a little shell function so we don't have to care about listing the columns in reverse order:

```
gencmd() {
    local arr
    # Sort arguments in descending order
    IFS=$'\n' arr=($(sort -nr <<< "$*"))
    printf 's/./&,/%d;' "${arr[@]}"
}

sed "$(gencmd 2 5 9)" myFile
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 3 4 *' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file
10,100,1000,10000
20,200,2000,20000
```

You'll need a newer version of gawk for `*` at the end of FIELDWIDTHS to mean "whatever's left", with older version just choose a large number like `999`.